# One menu, many levels, few editors

Tags: 7, routes, users, nodes

How can I have 1 menu (site map), hierarchical structure like:

- Dept 1

  - Abc
  - Def
  - Ghi
- Dept 4

  - AAA
  - BBB

    - ffe
    - ffg
    - ffx
  - CCC

With possibility to delegate editing permission of subtrees to some users?
I.e. : main admin edits the whole menu, admin A edits only submenu in Dept1, admin B edits only submenu BBB in submenu Dept 4 ...

Is there any module which can be used to do that? I know that Organic Groups has possibility of creating menus for every group with feature of editing permission to group members. But I'd rather have 1 big menu for the whole site...

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified which Drupal version you are using, but check out [Menu Subtree Permissions](http://drupal.org/project/menu_stp) for D6.

Comment: It's D7 what I have but thanks anyway - maybe I will take a look into source code if there's nothing like this for D7.

Comment: Please tag your question (and any future questions) with the correct drupal version, to avoid any more wasted answers. I have now added the D7 tag to your question.

Comment: Does anyone know DRUPAL 7 equivalent for mentioned module: "MENU SUBTREE PERMISSIONS" ?